# Qt Jambi: QTreeView with Custom Model?

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

I'm attempting to create a tree view in QT using Java to display something similar to

```
+ Category A
| + Category AB
| | Item AB
| \ Item A
+ Category B
| \ Item B
\ Item
```

with a custom `QAbstractItemModel` while following [the guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html).

There seems to be some issues with how [Qt Jambi](https://github.com/OmixVisualization/qtjambi) has implemented the wrapper for `QModelIndex`. There doesn't appear to be a way to create new instances of it like you can in the Qt guide and it appears to be missing function wrappers (at least `isValid` and `internalPointer`).

Here is the code I currently have based on [the guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html):
`TreeModel`

```
package playground;

import io.qt.core.*;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public final class TreeModel extends QAbstractItemModel {
    private final TreeItem rootItem;

    public TreeModel(QString data, QObject parent) {
        super(parent);

        rootItem = new TreeItem(Stream.of(tr("Title"), tr("Summary")).map(QVariant::new).toList(), null);
        setupModelData(data.split('\n'), rootItem);
    }

    private void setupModelData(QStringList split, TreeItem rootItem) {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public QModelIndex index(int row, int column, QModelIndex parent) {
        if(!hasIndex(row, column, parent)) {
            return new QModelIndex();
        }

        var parentItem = !parent.isValid() ? rootItem : parent.internalPointer();
        var child = parentItem.child(row);

        return child != null ? createIndex(row, column, childItem) : new QModelIndex();
    }

    @Override
    public QModelIndex parent(QModelIndex index) {
        if(!index.isValid()) {
            return new QModelIndex();
        }

        var childItem = index.internalPointer();
        var parentItem = childItem.parentItem();

        if(parentItem == rootItem) {
            return new QModelIndex();
        }

        return createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem);
    }

    @Override
    public int rowCount(QModelIndex parent) {
        if(parent.column() > 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        var parentItem = !parent.isValid() ? rootItem : parent.internalPointer();
        return parentItem.childCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int columnCount(QModelIndex parent) {
        return (parent.isValid() ? parent.internalPointer() : rootItem).columnCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object data(QModelIndex index, int role) {
        if(!index.isValid()) {
            return new QVariant();
        }

        if(role != Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole) {
            return new QVariant();
        }

        var item = index.internalPointer();
        return item.data(index.column());
    }

    @Override
    public Qt.ItemFlags flags(QModelIndex index) {
        return !index.isValid() ? new Qt.ItemFlags() : index.flags();
    }

    @Override
    public Object headerData(int section, Qt.Orientation orientation, int role) {
        if(orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal && role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole) {
            return rootItem.data(section);
        }

        return new QVariant();
    }
}
```

`TreeItem`:

```
package playground;

import io.qt.core.QVariant;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class TreeItem {
    private final List<TreeItem> childItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<QVariant> itemData = new ArrayList<>();
    private final TreeItem parentItem;

    public TreeItem(List<QVariant> data, TreeItem parent) {
        this.itemData.addAll(data);
        this.parentItem = parent;
    }

    public void appendChild(TreeItem child) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(child);
        childItems.add(child);
    }

    public TreeItem child(int row) {
        if(row < 0 || row >= childItems.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        return childItems.get(row);
    }

    public int childCount() {
        return childItems.size();
    }

    public int columnCount() {
        return itemData.size();
    }

    public QVariant data(int column) {
        if(column < 0 || column >= itemData.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        return itemData.get(column);
    }

    public int row() {
        if(parentItem != null) {
            return parentItem.childItems.indexOf(this);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public TreeItem parentItem() {
        return parentItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured this one out after someone pointed me in the correct direction on a different platform.

Turns out you need to go though a `QAbstractItemModel` method to create an instance of a `QModelIndex` and you also need to create your own "invalid" indexes instead of using a no-args method.

Instead of using `new QModelIndex()` you need to use `QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(-1, -1, 0)`. Instead of `QModelIndex.isValid` you need to do something like the following:

```
public static boolean isIndexValid(QModelIndex index) {
    return index != null && index.row() >= 0 && index.column() >= 0 && index.model() != null;
}
```

Finally instead of using the internal ID stuff as if it was a pointer you need to keep your own record of IDs. My basic implementation is as follows:

```
private final Map<Long, TreeItem> idToItemMap = new HashMap<>();
private final Map<TreeItem, Long> itemToIdMap = new HashMap<>();
private long nextId = 1;

private long getId(TreeItem childItem) {
    long id = itemToIdMap.getOrDefault(childItem, -1L);
    if(id == -1) {
        id = nextId++;
        itemToIdMap.put(childItem, id);
        idToItemMap.put(id, childItem);
    }
    return id;
}

private TreeItem getItem(QModelIndex index) {
    var item = idToItemMap.get(index.internalId());
    if(item == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("item was null: " + index);
    }
    return item;
}
```

(Don't use this in production code that can remove items from the model, it will keep references and leak memory. Append only should be okay.)